# get query result on php array and check if Variable iniside it or not

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i make mysql query , i want get a result from it and clean text before i check if Variable inside this result or not .. so i need to get this result on php array .

```
$ckeck = $db->query_read(" SELECT pagetext FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . " post "); 
while($ckeckpagetext = $db->fetch_array($ckeck))
{
// result from query - here i must make this in php array - that's my problem ? 
$pagetext = $ckeckpagetext['pagetext'];
$pagetext = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $pagetext);
$pagetext = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu','',$pagetext);

// Variable 
$message = $post['message'];
$message = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $message);
$message = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu','',$message);

// check if Variable inside array or not
if (in_array($message,$pagetext))
{
// do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add square brackets to make arrays, example
 `$pagetext[] = $ckeckpagetext['pagetext'];`
Your code above is rewriting a new pagetext variable every iteration

Comment: okay , but how i used `$pagetext[]` on `preg_replace` and `in_array`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the code too well the first time. The in_array function will not work because they are not arrays the way you have the code now. If you make them both arrays then you will have to work out what message in what pagetext. What exactly are you looking to pull out of each DB response ? Are they links you are looking for ? Can you post a sample response and show which bit you want to extract

Comment: `message` and `pagetext` are a text content, i clean them before i cheke if `message` is there same content in database or not .

Comment: So you're checking if a POST message is the same as the message in the DB, have I got that right ? Where are message and page text coming from ?

Comment: Yes, what you understood correctly ... post message come from php file like `newpost.php` , i make a plugin for vb forum , it job was to transfer a post if it duplicate, so I do first looks at the database that was the same content exists or not.

Comment: Could you do and SQL LIKE query with a portion of the pagetext and if it returns any rows then it's a duplicate? How much data do you need to check? Is it just a title or a whole text area?

Comment: yeah , i want check text area content , so .. i clean data befor i check if same content or not , `how much data ?` i don't know .. This is a question for the future, my code for any new post only not for old posts !

Comment: maybe i found Solution .. i make loop inside while `for($x=0; $x<$ckeck_num; $x++)
{
if ($message == $pagetext[$x])
{
$ckeck_duplicate = 1;
}
}` it's works but i cannot clean text when i used `$pagetext[]` how can i used it on `preg_replace`

Comment: Take out the square brackets as you are checking one message against one pagetext, As I said in my top comment I didn't get the question too well. You would be better off with a like statement in sql so that you are only pulling message that are not the same. It looks like you are pulling all the messages then checking in php, That's alot of bandwidth and processing power.

Comment: Well you may be right,if i used search as you said ,I want to search for content after the removal of links and images from it, how can i do this inside mysql query .. Example: can i use `preg_replace` in `LIKE` sql query ? - clean post area content  not a problem , but real problem is clean a field inside mysql query .. Is it not true? Must I do to extract the content first and then clean up the content

Comment: If you have a good way to do what i want , I will be happy ..if it not make load on the server

Comment: Right, let me get this straight. So you clean up the posted content from the message board, Then you want to check if the whole message is in the DB. You can't use preg replace in an sql query, PHP and SQL are different languages. The data in the DB should be clean already ?

Comment: Note: the users they will not put millions of new posts at same time,will be only a few new posts at one time .

Comment: no billy , you don't understand ... i not clean text when `insert` it on database ... only when i check .. why i do that ? may be user posted same content but put a different font color or a different font size elc .. so i clean text Before i check if exist or not .. but not clean posts on `insert query`

Comment: You should clean anything that you take in from the user, especially DB queries as not doing so leads to sql injection. Look up SQL LIKE queries, They're what you need.

Comment: i cannot do that becouse already ther is old posts on database .. anyway thank you , if you can help me on my code .. when i use for loop works but that is problem when i use square brackets like this `$pagetext[] = $ckeckpagetext['pagetext'];
$pagetext[] = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $pagetext);
$pagetext[] = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu','',$pagetext);`